# Здравствуйте, как в питоне спросить у есть ли два таких числа в списке?

Tags: python

нужно спрашивать у питона если в списке есть два одинаковых числа то то-то
если нет то ничего не делать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если два любых, то можно так:

```
my_list = [4, 4, 6]
my_set = set(my_list)
if len(my_set) < len(my_list):
    print('В списке были одинаковые элементы')
else:
    print('В списке не было одинаковых элементов')
```

Если 2 конкретных, можно так:

```
my_list = [4, 4, 6]
x = 4
if my_list.count(x) >= 2:
    print('В списке 2 или больше одинаковых элементов', x)
else:
    print('В списке не было двух элементов', x)
```

Если вам ничего не надо делать, если в списке не было одинаковых элементов, то блок `else` и то, что внутри него, удаляете из этого кода.